# How to remove html link from master page load function using session variable in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables, master-pages

I want to remove the links if the session variable is having value `available` in page load function.

```
if (Session["UserLogin"].ToString().Equals("available"))
   {
       HtmlAnchor linkCreateUser = (HtmlAnchor)this.Master.FindControl("linkCreateUsers");
       linkCreateUser.Visible = false;
   }
```

**Admin.Master**

```
<a href="CreateUser.aspx" runat="server" id="linkCreateUsers" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Create User</a>
```

I tried the above code. But it throws an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I created this session variable when user logged in on the login page.

Comment: On which line you are getting error is it at the time of "linkCreateUser" variable creation?

Comment: Are we sure this.Master.FindControl("linkCreateUsers") is actually finding something?

Answer (score 0):

Your code hides the link if you just run it. Your code propbably craches when the Session itself is null.

So check for that also.

```
if (Session["UserLogin"] != null && Session["UserLogin"].ToString().Equals("available"))
```